# C++ error inside function: expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++

I’m new to C++ and I’m trying to do something that should be overwhelmingly simple: generate a small array of random numbers (RV) between 0 and 1 by calling a function I call RandomVec. But its giving me an error in the function saying “double W expression must have pointer-to-object type”.

I don’t understand what I’m doing wrong, could someone tell me what this error is about and how I can solve it? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random> 
using namespace std; 

double RandomVec(double W, const int cols) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

    for (int element = 0; element < cols +1; element++) {
        W[element] = dis(gen);
    }
return W;
}

int main()
{
    const int cols = 4;

    double RV;
    double W;
    RV = RandomVec (W,cols);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This: `double W` is double. This: `double W[]` is an array of doubles.

Comment: What makes you actually think you can use an indexing `operator[]` with a `double` type? Who taught you so?

Answer (score 1):

You even said it yourself, you want to fill *an array*. If you look at your `W` definition, it's a single `double`, not an array.

Comment: Yes, but I tried first to declare it as `double W[cols+1];` so it would be of the correct size, but then I get another error saying _“argument of type double is incompatible with parameter of type double”_ while at the same time keeping my original error.. How does the function want me to create W?

Comment: @Petahanks _`double W[cols+1];'`_ VLA's aren't standard c++ compliant syntax. Use a `std::vector<double> W(cols+1);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access what is a plain old `double` as an array of doubles when you say `W[element]`. You must either create an array of doubles outside of `RandomVec(...)` or inside it and return it.

If you'd like to pass an array in, consider using `std::vector` in `main` and passing a reference to the vector in to `RandomVec`.

```
double RandomVec(std::vector<double>& vec, const int cols) {
  //...
  for (int element = 0; element < cols + 1; element++) {
    vec.push_back(dis(gen));
  }
}

int main {
  // ...
  std::vector<double> my_vector;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below a possible solution using vectors. If you want a vector with 4 columns, the index must run from 0 to `columns`, not `columns + 1`. If you choose to use `std::`, no need to add `using namespace std;` on top. Added a print out of the generated random vector at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <random>


std::vector<double> RandomVector(std::vector<double>& vector, const int columns) {

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

    for (int element = 0; element < columns; element++)
        vector.push_back(dis(gen));

    return vector;
}



int main() {

    const int columns = 4;
    std::vector<double> my_vector;

    my_vector = RandomVector(my_vector, columns);

    // print out generated random vector
    for (std::vector<double>::const_iterator i = my_vector.begin(); i != my_vector.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';

    // wait for a character to exit
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```